# Android: making 2 consecutive http requests

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley

I'm getting an address from the user and i'm using [GeoCoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) to get the lat/lng.

After getting the lat/lng I need to send a POST request to my server to save the data (using [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley)).

I'm running the GeoCoder request in an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and I run the post request in the `onPostExecute` callback.

Is that the right way to do it or is there a better way?

here is my code:

```
private class GeoCoderAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>>{

        @Override
        protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... params) {
            String address = params[0];
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(Favorites.this);
            try {
                addresses = coder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return addresses;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> result) {
            Utils.dismissDialog(progDialog);
            if (result != null) {
                Address address = result.get(0);
                ...
                //this makes a post request
                VolleyHelper.post(request,AppConstants.URL.FAVORITES, getFavoritesSuccess(), getFavoritesError(), progDialog);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else{
                Log.d(TAG, "Got Nothing!!!");
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Where are the 2 consecutive http requests in this code? I only see one!

Comment: @Lefteris - `VolleyHelper.post(request,AppConstants.URL.FAVORITES, getFavoritesSuccess(), getFavoritesError(), progDialog);`

Comment: That's the request I saw. Where is the second ?

Comment: @Lefteris - `GeoCoder.getFromLocationName()` is actually making an http request

Comment: Well you are running the Volley request on the postExecute, meaning that the first request has finished. So nothing wrong as far as I can see here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that your way is the best. As you commented, you need to wait until onPost to use volley so there is no way around it. Anyways, volley uses its own multi threading and so it won't lock anything up.

In general it is best to minimize http requests due to the battery cost from the radio, but in this case it is key to the functionality of your app so there is no way around it.

Btw, for anyone reading this question and curious about volley -http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score -2):

> I'm running the GeoCoder request in an AsyncTask and I run the post
>   request in the onPostExecute callback.
>
> Is that the right way to do it

No, because `onPostExecute` run on main ui Thread. if you do this then UI will freeze until Http post request not completed.

> or is there a better way?

Make `post` request from  `doInBackground` after getting `addresses` from `Geocoder`.

Comment: I'm using Volley library, so the post is also running in a background thread

Comment: I can't run it from `doInBackground` since it is async and the only time i know the address list is filled is in the `onPostExecute`